# Definite integrals (Riemann sums)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

[can anyone please help with th is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGUT3.png)

Saw the problem from schaums outline advanced calculus

Converting that to the limit of a sum I got:

[The sum I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgokg.png)

My question is how did that translate to
[The sum I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiMRy.png)

Comment: The bound should be $n-1$ not $n$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) for typesetting.

Comment: @stubbornAtom how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the integral as a Riemann sum is
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \text{RS}(f,a,b,n) =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} f \left( a + i \cdot \frac{b-a}{n} \right) \frac{b - a}{n}$$
It seems like in the sum you got the upper bound is $n$ instead of $n-1$. Taking the upper bound to be $n-1$, we get the sum
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin\left( \frac{kt}{n} \right)$$
Rewriting this we get
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin\left( \frac{kt}{n} \right) = \frac{1-0}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right)$$
Since if $k=0$, $\displaystyle{\sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t-0}{n} \right)} = 0$. We can just set the lower bound to $k=0$. Continuing, we have
$$\frac{1-0}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right) = \frac{1-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right)$$
Now, we manipulate the fraction at the start to get
$$\frac{1-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{t} \frac{t-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right)$$
Next, we can rewrite this sum as an integral from $0$ to $t$:
$$\frac{1}{t} \frac{t-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \sin(x) \, dx$$
Finally, we can see that if we want the Riemann sum of the integral
$$\int_0^t \sin(x) \, dx$$
We need to multiply both sides of our equation by $t$:
$$\frac{1}{t} \frac{t-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \sin(x) \, dx \Rightarrow$$ $$\int_0^t \sin(x) \, dx = \frac{t-0}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left( 0 + k\frac{t - 0}{n} \right)$$
Which after simplification equals
$$\frac{t}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin \left( \frac{kt}{n} \right)$$

Comment: @Vector Does this answer your question? If there are some unclear parts, I can rewrite it with more steps if you like.

Comment: I think i get it now but for how I got the upper limit as n I used  Sn=S(n-1)+Tn sorry I don't know how to type math equations here yet just joined today Sn(summation of nth terms)  This is correct right?

Comment: I think i get i should be able to use math Jaxon now so this is what I meant  let  $$\Omega = Lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Sin\frac{kt}{n}$$    $$\Omega = Lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}Sin\frac{kt}{n}-Lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} sin{ \frac{nt}{n} }$$  $$And \ Lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} sin{ \frac{nt}{n} }=0$$ so   is equal to  $$\Omega = Lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}Sin\frac{kt}{n}$$

Comment: @Vector, yes this is correct. But not a necessary step, as the Riemann sum definition of the integral has an upper bound of $n-1$. Setting the upper bound to $n$ gets you further away from the answer. Also, if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it by clicking the check-mark next to it.